# Dracaena marginata "Magenta" black spots

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, leaves, dracaena

Anybody knows what these black spots are? And how I can get rid of them?

[image: Black spots on Dracaena marginata "Magenta"]

Comment: It might could be scales. Did you inspect the things after scraping them of the leaves?